# Permission error on wordpress theme from themeforest

Tags: wordpress, permissions, wordpress-theming, file-permissions

I am using a custom theme I brought from themeforest and I am trying to deploy it to WordPress a

> WPHunters Health Checker have detected next problems:
> Set 0777 permissions to /wp-content folder.
> To use theme please fix these issues. This message visible only for site administrators.

I have tried to change the permissions using FileZilla but WordPress is not allowing me to change the permissions to 777.

[Theme link](https://themeforest.net/item/ph-responsive-wedding-photography-wordpress-theme/20012504?s_rank=3)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, WordPress doesn't have a functionality that allows admins to change permission from the admin panel if I understood you correctly. I dont know what you mean by "but WordPress is not allowing me to change the permissions to 777." Just make sure to chmod recursively.

Go to FileZilla and navigate to the path :  /wp-content folder
Right click on the folder and choose File permission
Set the numerical value to 777
Check the box that says Rescuers into subdirectories
Select Apply to all files and directories

Comment: thanks but it didnt work.

Comment: Try to disable your plugins and reactivate them again. If the issue persist, it means that your php running as apache or php user, to be able to chmod ( change permissions) inside folder, you have to change the owner of this folder to be YOU. I assume you are on a shared hosting and that is what they usually do is to set permissions that you can not overwrite. Contact your host and ask them to change the Apache ownership to be YOU.